# Error compiling Autorest Generated Client

Tags: c#, autorest

After autogenerating client using Swagger OpenApi 3.0 spec, I'm unable to compile the generated client. I get error on objects **ClientDiagnostics**, **RawRequestUriBuilder**, **Utf8JsonRequestContent**.

RestClient.cs

```
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT License.

// <auto-generated/>

#nullable disable

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure;
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Core.Pipeline;
using Planner.Client.Models;

namespace Planner.Client
{
    internal partial class RestClient
    {
        private Uri endpoint;
        private ClientDiagnostics _clientDiagnostics;
        private HttpPipeline _pipeline;

        /// <summary> Initializes a new instance of RestClient. </summary>
        /// <param name="clientDiagnostics"> The handler for diagnostic messaging in the client. </param>
        /// <param name="pipeline"> The HTTP pipeline for sending and receiving REST requests and responses. </param>
        /// <param name="endpoint"> server parameter. </param>
        public RestClient(ClientDiagnostics clientDiagnostics, HttpPipeline pipeline, Uri endpoint = null)
        {
            endpoint ??= new Uri("https://localhost:49157");

            this.endpoint = endpoint;
            _clientDiagnostics = clientDiagnostics;
            _pipeline = pipeline;
        }


        internal HttpMessage CreateCreateDataRequest(IEnumerable<DataCreateModel> body)
        {
            var message = _pipeline.CreateMessage();
            var request = message.Request;
            request.Method = RequestMethod.Post;
            var uri = new RawRequestUriBuilder();
            uri.Reset(endpoint);
            uri.AppendPath("/api/Budget/CreateData", false);
            request.Uri = uri;
            if (body != null)
            {
                request.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
                var content = new Utf8JsonRequestContent();
                content.JsonWriter.WriteStartArray();
                foreach (var item in body)
                {
                    content.JsonWriter.WriteObjectValue(item);
                }
                content.JsonWriter.WriteEndArray();
                request.Content = content;
            }
            return message;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, getting error in below autogenerated serialization class on **IUtf8JsonSerializable** and **Optional**.

DataCreateModel.Serialization.cs

```
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT License.

// <auto-generated/>

#nullable disable

using System.Text.Json;
using Azure.Core;

namespace Planner.Client.Models
{
    public partial class DataCreateModel : IUtf8JsonSerializable
    {
        void IUtf8JsonSerializable.Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            if (Optional.IsDefined(ProjectCode))
            {
                if (ProjectCode != null)
                {
                    writer.WritePropertyName("projectCode");
                    writer.WriteStringValue(ProjectCode);
                }
                else
                {
                    writer.WriteNull("projectCode");
                }
            }
            if (Optional.IsDefined(TeamCode))
            {
                if (TeamCode != null)
                {
                    writer.WritePropertyName("teamCode");
                    writer.WriteStringValue(TeamCode);
                }
                else
                {
                    writer.WriteNull("teamCode");
                }
            }
            if (Optional.IsDefined(YearMonth))
            {
                writer.WritePropertyName("yearMonth");
                writer.WriteNumberValue(YearMonth.Value);
            }
            if (Optional.IsDefined(Hours))
            {
                writer.WritePropertyName("hours");
                writer.WriteNumberValue(Hours.Value);
            }
            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
    }
}
```

This project using .net 5, autorest v3.1.0, cli v3.1.2 and node v14.15.5.

What am I missing?

Comment: Whenever you report that you get an error, please be specific about *exactly what that error is*.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed it would be clear the error was on the objects I had in bold. I should have been more explicit. The error was Object not found during compilation.

Comment: "Object not found" - or the specific classes not being found? It would be so much clearer if you'd just copy/paste the error messages directly into the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have add only this changes and it works

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <IncludeGeneratorSharedCode>true</IncludeGeneratorSharedCode>
  <RestoreAdditionalProjectSources>https://azuresdkartifacts.blob.core.windows.net/azure-sdk-tools/index.json</RestoreAdditionalProjectSources>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Azure.Core" Version="1.10.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.AutoRest.CSharp" Version="3.0.0-beta.20210311.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
</ItemGroup>
```

For the client creation i use this

```
class MyClientOptions : ClientOptions
{
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var client = new TestRestClient(
        new ClientDiagnostics(new MyClientOptions()),
        new HttpPipeline(HttpClientTransport.Shared),
        new Uri("https://api.domain.com"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Adding reference to Microsoft.Azure.AutoRest.CSharp worked for me.

Comment: What's the nuget package source? I'm getting

"Unable to find package Microsoft.Azure.AutoRest.CSharp. No packages exist with this id in source(s): DevExpress nuget.org"

Is it no longer beta and been renamed?

Comment: Ah, I think the 

  <RestoreAdditionalProjectSources>https://azuresdkartifacts.blob.core.windows.net/azure-sdk-tools/index.json</RestoreAdditionalProjectSources>
 in the propertygroup in Anton's answer is what provides it

Comment: Great answer! This was really blocking me and now it's working great.

Comment: If only this would have been explained in the Autorest docs... I have not found anything :(

Comment: I tried the above suggestions and I could still see some other new issues in my project in auto generated code as follows: It is creating duplicate switch cases for success response and it is trying to set response as nullable bool for 500 errors whereas the actual method has bool return type. So, the reason behind that is the Microsoft.Azure.AutoRest.CSharp package is not fully released yet. I don't personally recommend to go with --v3 flag to generate client code for real projects.  For now, I am going with --version=3.0.6274 for generating client and it is working for me without any issues.

Comment: The URL in `RestoreAdditionalProjectSources` changed to https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/azure-sdk/public/_packaging/azure-sdk-for-net/nuget/v3/index.json and also the versions are higher. autorest (now?) generates a project file as well - look up the values there.

Answer (score 6):

It seems new autorest requires some changes in csproj.

For my case, I had to change it to

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  <Nullable>annotations</Nullable>
  <IncludeGeneratorSharedCode>true</IncludeGeneratorSharedCode>
  <RestoreAdditionalProjectSources>https://azuresdkartifacts.blob.core.windows.net/azure-sdk-tools/index.json</RestoreAdditionalProjectSources>
  <LangVersion>8</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
  
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Azure.Core" Version="1.10.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.AutoRest.CSharp" Version="3.0.0-beta.20210311.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
</ItemGroup>
```